# Find $g$ if $g''$ exists but discontinuous on $[a, b]$ and $\frac{1}{x-c}\int_c^x g(t)\ dt=g(\frac{c+x}{2})$ for any $c\in [a, b)$ and $x\in (c, b]$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

If a function $g$ has a continuous second derivative and satisfies

$$
\frac{1}{x-c}\int_c^x g(t)\ dt=g(\frac{c+x}{2}),
$$

for all $c\in [a, b)$ and $x\in(c, b]$. Then it follows that $g$ is linear.

If $g''$ is discontinuous, then $g$ must be non-linear. However, is there any example of $g$ that satisfies the above equation in this case?

Comment: Of course not. $g$ integrable implies $g$ continous. Then $g$ continous implies $g'$  exists and is continous on $(a,b)$ and $$g(y)=g(\frac{x+y}{2})+\frac{y-x}{2}g'(\frac{x+y}{2}).$$ This implies that $g''$ exists and is continous on $(a,b).$

Comment: @GérardLetac, the discontinuous step function is integrable. The absolute function  is continuous but not differentiable. Most importantly, I don't see why the equality implies $g''$ exists and is continuous.

Comment: $y\mapsto (y-x) g(\frac{x+y}{2})=\int_x^yg(t)dt$ is continuous since $g$ is integrable, hence $g$ is continuous. By the fundamental theorem of calculus $y\mapsto (y-x) g(\frac{x+y}{2})$ has a continuous derivative, hence $g'$ exists and is continuous. etc.